# Multi Tenant (Software As Service) ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant

I am in the process of planning and designing a Multi Tenant (Software As Service) ASP.Net MVC Application.

Each tenant will use the application as a service to provide services to its own customers.

I am clear on the thing that I can use a subdomain to identify between different tenants e-g abc.myapplication.com or xyz.myapplication.com with 'abc' and 'xyz' being two tenants.

The above scenario will not hide the fact that tenant abc and xyz are using myapplication as their service provider.

What if I don't want to follow the above approach and want to identify the tenants differently.

I don't want it to be obvious that this tenant is using myapplication as service provider underneath.

Is there a way that each tenant can access myapplication using different urls altogether most preferably using their own domain or any other logical way to achieve this?

**The final scenario I want to achieve is that myapplication will serve as serviceprovider to all its tenants.
All the tenants will have their own customer/accounts.
The tenants will use subdomains to identify between its accounts e-g customer1.{tenanturl} and cutomer2.{tenanturl}.**

**What should be the {tenanturl} so that it hides the fact that tenant is using myapplication as its service provider**

I would really appreciate all the help on this.

Comment: There's no difference between `xyz.myapplication.com` and `app.company.com`, they are just DNS records, which would/could be pointing to your app. With this in mind you just have to make sure your underlying business logic is robust enough to handle both scenarios (i.e. using the entire host name).

Comment: @BrentMannering
Thanks Brent
One thing more each tenant of myapplication will be using subdomain methodologies to differentiate between its own customers. e-g cust1.abc.com and cust2.abc.com. Assuming If I am using app.company.com for tenant abc will it become cust1.app.abc.com and cust2.app.abc.com for customer identification for the tenant?

Comment: @BrentMannering Will this also means that every tenant signing up with my application has to update dns records for his domain as this app.{tenantdomain}.com to point it to myapplication public IP address?

Comment: Again having `cust1.app.company.com` is no different, it's just another DNS record. However it may prove easier to incorporate the customer context into the path portion of the URL e.g. `app.company.com/customer1/`, otherise if your client has 100+ customers, you'll be trying to create 100+ DNS entries, and 100+ IIS bindings etc. In short not easily maintainable.

Comment: Also, it will prove to be a SSL Certificate horror. Imagine if a tenant doesn't have SSL for their domain.